# DataTable 1.9.4 fnRowCallback giving wrong aData

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm getting a weird bug from fnRowCallback, the aData parameter is giving me the right data, 
but with an added a key {"":""}

```
fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
    console.log(aData) // logs { ... right data ..., "":""}
}
```

Why Does that happen ?

**UPDATE:** More code

```
$("#datatable").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPageLast": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
    "sAjaxSource": get_route('get_registries', $('#base-name').text()),
    "aoColumns": TABLE_DATA.columns,
    "bFilter": true,
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
         console.log(aData) // logs { ... right data ..., "":""}
    },
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "Não foram encontrados registros",
        "sInfo": "<span>Exibindo de <b>_START_</b> até <b>_END_</b> de <b>_TOTAL_</b> registros encontrados.</span>",
        "sInfoEmpty": " ",
        "sInfoFiltered": "",
        "sInfoThousands": ".",
        "sLengthMenu": "Exibir _MENU_ registros",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
        "sProcessing": "Processando...",
        "sSearch": "Pesquisa:",
        "sZeroRecords": "Não foram encontrados registros"
    }
});
```

Comment: Need to see more code, how is your datatable defined?

Comment: Updated, got more code